# Trying to add a column but getting a condition has length >1 error

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:nrow(y)){
  if (y$first_completed_date == NA) {
    y$comp[i]<-1
  }
  else {
    y$comp[i]<-0
  }
}
```

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in if (yumi$first_completed_date == NA) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Change your `if` condition to `if (is.na(y$first_completed_date[i]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is.na` can be used for creating a logical expression for `NA` elements instead of `==`.  Also, warning is because we are using `if/else` and not `ifelse` as `if/else` is not vectorized.  The straightforward option would be to create the logical expression with `is.na` and coerce that to binary with `as.integer` so that `TRUE -> 1` and `FALSE ->0`

```
y$comp <- as.integer(is.na(y$first_completed_date))
```